# espressjs, node, mongo saving method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-mongodb-native

i have this function "saveUser", which gets value from textbox, and updates information of the user and then uses ajax to post the object to our updateuser service.

```
function saveUser(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    var errorCount = 0;
    $('#editUser input').each(function(index, val) {
      if($(this).val() === '') { errorCount++; }
      });

    if(errorCount === 0) {
       var existingUser = {
        'username': $('#editUser fieldset input#inputUserName').val(),
        'email': $('#editUser fieldset input#inputUserEmail').val(),
        'fullname': $('#editUser fieldset input#inputUserFullname').val(),
        'age': $('#editUser fieldset input#inputUserAge').val(),
        'location': $('#editUser fieldset input#inputUserLocation').val(),
        'gender': $('#editUser fieldset input#inputUserGender').val()
         }

         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: existingUser,
            url: '/users/updateuser/' + data_id,
            dataType: 'JSON'
         }).done(function( response ) {


        if (response.msg === '') {
            $('#editUser fieldset input').val('');
            populateTable();
            disableSaveBtn();
        }
        else {

            alert('Error: ' + response.msg);
        }
    });
}
  else {
      alert('Please fill in all fields');
      return false;
      }
 };
```

and this is the code for updateuser service.

```
  router.put('/updateuser/:id',function(req, res){
     var id = req.params.id;
     var user = req.body;
     delete user._id;
     console.log('Updating user: ' + id);
     console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
     db.collection('userlist', function(err, result) {
        collection.update({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, user, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {
           if (err) {
               console.log('Error updating user: ' + err);
               res.send({'error':'An error has occurred'});
           } else {
               console.log('' + result + ' document(s) updated');
               res.send(user);
                  }
       });      
   });
});
```

when i click into users account and i edited it, then saving it,

i get this on my console:

```
POST /users/updateuser/53aca86c005afcbc0faac5be 404 128ms - 1.08kb
```

all of my operations are good, except for this operation. the adding user is working good, the deletion of user is working also, the retrieving of user based on the id is good also, except with this saving operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making post request. But your router is handling PUT request

Use instead

```
router.post('/updateuser/:id',function(req, res){
```

Comment: yeah, ive tried that before but my console returns me this:

Comment: 'POST /users/updateuser/53aca81c005afcbc0faac5ba 500 130ms - 1.1kb'

Comment: I bet you can see some error message as well in the server logs. From back here I can see a reference to an undefined `collection` variable.

Comment: okay, can i upload to whole app into the mediafire so you guys can know exactly what i want to happen.

Comment: it works!! here the code. :3

        var db = req.db;
        var id = req.params.id;
        var user = req.body;
        delete user._id;
        console.log('Updating user: ' + id);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
        db.collection('userlist').update({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, user,

Comment: var db = req.db;
    var id = req.params.id;
    var user = req.body;
    delete user._id;
    console.log('Updating user: ' + id);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
        db.collection('userlist').update({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, user, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {